# Отображение букв в виде чисел

Tags: c++, ascii

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <clocale>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
        
    char c = 'б';
    int a = c;
    cout << a << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Если в char c вписать английскую букву, то отобразиться число(cовпадающая с ascii), но если вписать русскую, то мой компилятор отображает отрицательное число а на сайте onlinegdb.com выдает ошибку, как быть?

Comment: Во-первых, в ascii нет русских символов. Во-вторых, тип char (предполагая, что его размер 8 бит) способен хранить только числа от -128 до 127

Comment: я сверялся с этим сайтом [https://snipp.ru/handbk/table-ascii], как тогда сделать так чтоб эта таблица совпадала с выводом?

Comment: Во первых, используйте не `char`, а `unsigned char`, и во-вторых -- убедитесь, что исходный текст вы вводите в кодировке cp-1251 (ошибка на сайте onlinegdb.com, о которой вы пишете,   видимо связана с тем, что этот сайт использует кодировку utf-8)

Comment: Можете подсказать как установить кодировку сp-1251 или где можно прочесть про это?